# WordPress debugging

Tags: wordpress, logging

How can I write debug messages from my WordPress plugin?

*[Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)* describes how can I enable the `wp-content/debug.log` file. But how can I write to it? Is there any logging method like `wp_log($msg)` or something? I didn't find such.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is set to true, the [`error_log`-INI setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) is set:

```
ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
```

To write to that file, you can use the [`error_log`-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php):

```
error_log("This message is written to the log file");
```

This function is not specific to WordPress and can be used in any PHP script.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple function you can use; it will only log a message if [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) is enabled:

```php
function log_me($message) {
    if ( WP_DEBUG === true ) {
        if ( is_array($message) || is_object($message) ) {
            error_log( print_r($message, true) );
        } else {
            error_log( $message );
        }
    }
}
```

You can call the `log_me()` function like this in your theme template(s):

```
log_me( 'This is a message for debugging purposes' );
```

Which will appear in your `/wp-content/debug.log` as the following line:

```
[13-Apr-2013 20:59:17 UTC] This is a message for debugging purposes
```